# How to prevent new tab creation in puppeteer's chromium instance?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I would like to prevent new tab creation. Either by clicking 'new tab button' either by window.open method.
Is there any way to listen on new tab creation. I don't mean 'targetcreated' event because then tab is already created. Maybe there is something similar to event.preventDefault?

Below is a very simple code that closes every new tab but I think it's very ugly and I want to improve it.

```
browser.on('targetcreated', (target) => {
    function closeNewTabs(target) {
      let targetBrowser = target.browser();
      targetBrowser.pages().then(data => {
          if (data.length>1) {
              for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  if (i>1) data[i].close();
              }
          }
      })
    }
})
```

Comment: Seems like you are using iframe to connect another site so you can't control the pop-up behavior?

Comment: No, my problem is not related with that - it's rather with chromium behaviour. I would like to have always fixed number of tabs and prevent opening new ones.

Answer (score 4):

A possible workaround would be to listen to [targetcreated](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-targetcreated) event and then [page.close](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagecloseoptions)

It would be something similar to

```
browser.on("targetcreated", async (target)=>{
   const page=await target.page();
   if(page) page.close();
});
```

It doesn't prevent creating new tabs, but it should close them immediately after opening